# Removing array schema element in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am removing accepted proposals from my database.So by making ProjectSubmit.pending = true ,I am updating my database.But when I accepted these proposals I added them into a array schema and now i want to remove that index from array.

That's my schema :

```js
const SupervisorSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    name: String,
    password: String,
    username: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    proposals: [{
        type: String
    }],
    secretToken: { type: String }
});
```

This is my route :

```js
router.get('/remove-accepted-proposal/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    
    ProjectSubmit.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id : req.params.id},{pending: true},function(err, supervisor) 
            {
                if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(err);
                }else{
                    next();
                }
            });
    Supervisor.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.proposals }).then((supervisor) => {
        res.redirect('/supervisor-list');
    });


});
```

How can I remove that element?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you say remove from the database do you mean remove from the collection? Can you let me see a sample structure of that object field assuming you already have say 3 different elements. Pls give example and also elaborate what you intend to do. Give a use case example. thanks

Comment: Yap,want to remove from collection.Here in my schema,proposals is array type object.So when I am inserting proposals,a proposal id is inserted in that proposals collection.So,when I am deleting the proposal I need to delete that proposal id from proposals array as well.So here I just want to find that id from proposals array obeject but I don't find anyway of finding array objects.